# Seeking a Function that vanishes at edge of unit square along with normal derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I have a system of PDEs defined over $D=[0,1]^2$. I want to choose an initial condition that is consistent with the boundary conditions I am applying. One way to do this would be to require:
$$ \phi=\phi_x=\phi_y=0 \text{ at } \partial D $$
$$ \phi(x,y,0) \in [0,1]\  \forall \  (x,y)\in\  D $$
I'm not quite sure how to approach this though. I thought to use sines $\frac{1}{2}(\sin(\pi x)+\sin(\pi z))$ so the function would vanish at the corners but then this isn't true over the entire boundary and it doesn't ensure the derivatives vanish either. I don't think a polynomial will work but I'm not quite sure. Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Note that if $\phi$ vanishes at $x_0$, then $\phi^2$ has vanishing derivatives at $x_0$ by the product rule. Also, if you have finitely many functions vanishing at parts of the boundary, such that at any point some function vanishes, then their product vanishes on the whole boundary.

Comment: Ah thanks for the hint: looks like $\phi(x,y,0)= 10xy(x-1)(y-1)$ works just fine.